# How to make the scala based spark job avoid always waiting to insert data into a locked postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one scala based spark job running in the AWS EMR cluster, which ingests data into some PostgreSQL tables. There are two steps in ingesting the data.

Step 1. To write the dataframe into some staging table.

```
outputDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, "staging.customer", connproperties)
```

Step 2. To run the SQL statement to move data from staging table into main table. It is similar as below.

```
query_insertion = "INSERT INTO main.customer(CustomerName, City, Country) SELECT SupplierName, City, Country FROM staging.customer;"

val st = conn.createStatement()
st.executeUpdate(query_insertion)
```

If the staging table or main table is locked, the spark job will keep on waiting without stopping. I want to have the solution that it will generate an alert and then stop if it waits for a certain period of time. Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Do you know why table is getting locked? You could query the metadata for the table from postgres for the table and check first if it is locked or not and have some retry mechanism based on some timeframe. In that case you do not have to worry about the locked table. if the no of retries gets completed you can log the info and stop the job.

Comment: Thanks. The table is locked mainly due to another ongoing ingestion. It is a good idea to query metadata before trying to inserting data into table. Besides that, are there some options for spark/scala, such as timeout settings, in writing dataframe into table or execute sql statement?